# ERROR during macroexpansion of (LOOP FOR A ...)

Tags: loops, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a Lisp program that implements a board game very similar to dots and boxes, meaning that I have two players who compete against each other but who can make consecutive moves. I am trying to implement the simplest minimax algorithm to achieve this, without alpha beta pruning and assuming that the moves are alternate. Since I'm new to Common Lisp, I would appreciate any feed back you could give me, but particularly why the following error occurs when I try to compile my file:

```
caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (LOOP FOR A ...).
;   Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept.
```

Here is the code I have so far. A problem is a game. The `initial-state` I this it's self-explanatory. The `terminal-test-p` receives the current game state and indicates if this is a terminal one. The `player` function receives the current game state and indicates which player's turn it is to play. The `actions` function receives the current game state and returns a list of all actions available in that state. The `result` function receives the current game state and an action and returns the game state that results of applying that action to the state. Finally, the `utility-function` receives the current game state and the id of the player and returns the number of points expected for that player.

```
(defstruct problem
  initial-state
  player
  actions
  result
  terminal-test-p
  utility-function)
```

This is the minimax I have so far. I know it's still pretty poor, but I really can't advance much since I'm not understanding much of this language.

```
(defparameter *infinity* 999999999)

(defun minimax (prob int)
  (let ((action nil)
        (utility nil)
        (current-state (problem-initial-state prob)))
    (loop for a in (funcall (problem-actions prob) current-state)
          (setq next-prob (make-problem
                              :initial-state (funcall (problem-result prob)
                                                      current-state a)))
      (if (> (min-value next-prob int) utility)
          (progn  
            (setf action a)
            (setf utility (min-value next-prob int)))))
(values action utility)))
```

Function `MAX-VALUE`:

```
(defun max-value (prob int)
  (if (funcall (problem-terminal-test-p prob))
      (return-from max-value (funcall (problem-utility-function prob)
                                      (problem-initial-state prob))))
  (let ((utility (- *infinity*)))
    (loop for a in (funcall (problem-actions prob)
                            (problem-initial-state prob))
          (let ((next-prob (make-problem
                             :initial-state (funcall (problem-result prob)
                                                     (problem-initial-state prob)
                                                     a))))
            (setf utility (max utility (min-value next-prob int)))))
    utility))
```

Function `MIN-VALUE`:

```
(defun min-value (prob int)
  (if (fun call (problem-terminal-test-p prob))
      (return-from min-value (funcall (problem-utility-function prob)
                                      (problem-initial-state prob))))
  (let ((utility *infinity*))
    (loop for a in (funcall (problem-actions prob) (problem-initial-state prob))
          (let ((next-prob (make-problema
                            :initial-state (fun call
                                                (problem-result prob)
                                                (problem-initial-state prob)
                                                a))))
            (setf utility (min utility (max-value next-prob int)))))
    utility))
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the entire error message?  @LarsBrinkhoff's answer answers this, but I notice that in SBCL's output, the line after "caught error during macroexpansion…" is (in a simplified example) "`(SETQ …)` found where `LOOP` keyword expected \ current `LOOP` context: `FOR A IN … (SETQ …)`." which seems to point out exactly what and where the error is…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `DO` in your `LOOP`.  It should look like this:

```
(loop for a in (funcall (problem-actions prob) current-state)
      DO (setq next-prob (make-problem :initial-state (funcall (problem-result prob) current-state a)))
      ...)
```

Comment: Can't believe it was as simple as that... thank you!